# H2 database complaints about sql syntax error with a valid mysql query

Tags: java, h2

I created an in-memory H2 database (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) as following

```
public static HikariConfig createHikariConfigH2(String schema, String pathToSchemaSql) {
    LOGGER.info("Creating schema {} and execute sql {}", schema, pathToSchemaSql);
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:" + schema + ";"

            + "MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE"

            + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" + ";INIT= drop schema if exists " + schema + " CASCADE\\;create schema " + schema
            + "\\;SET SCHEMA " + schema + "\\;"

            + "runscript from 'classpath:/" + pathToSchemaSql + "'");
    config.setUsername("sa");
    config.setPassword("");
    return config;
}
```

Then I try to run an sql query as follows

```
HikariConfig config = createHikariConfigH2(“schema”, “a.sql”);
        try (HikariDataSource master = new HikariDataSource(config);
                Connection conn = master.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                        "DELETE mt FROM tableA AS mt,tableB AS et WHERE mt.id = et.id AND et._iud = 'D'")) {
            try (ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
                while (result.next()) {
                    String tableName = result.getString(1);
                    tables.add(tableName);
                }
            }
        }
```

But it complaints about a syntax error but the **same query works fine on  normal mysql db**.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "delete mt from tableA as mt,[*]tableB as et where mt.id = et.id and et._iud = 'D' "; SQL statement:
DELETE mt FROM tableA AS mt,tableB AS et WHERE mt.id = et.id AND et._iud = 'D' [42000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:989)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:686)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627)
```

In the mysql compatibility section (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) , I could not find anything related to this.

Could someone please help

Comment: To verify the query, try running the query in a MySQL DB. I think there is some mistake in your query

Comment: Because [`DELETE`](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#delete) in H2 does not support `delete mt from ...`. So does [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html). What do you want this SQL to do?

Comment: @LutzHorn Thanks. I did not see that link

Comment: @LutzHorn from what i see (at first sight) [here](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/Parser.java#L1343) it seams H2 should support the multitable syntax from MySQL..

Comment: Maybe, but not `delete mt from ...`.

Comment: did you notice the [readIdentifierWithSchema()](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/Parser.java#L4832) function? @LutzHorn  that function has a `String s = readColumnIdentifier();` line.... Seams `DELETE ... FROM` syntax is more or less implemented maybe it fails because of alias usage as iam not sure jet where `readColumnIdentifier()` is defined..

Comment: So maybe `DELETE tableA FROM tableA,tableB WHERE tableA.id = tableB .id AND tableB ._iud = 'D'` works but generally use should use a `INNER JOIN` -> `DELETE tableA FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id AND tableB._iud = 'D'` .. but the simple fix is indeed @KarolDowbecki 's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like H2 doesn't support syntax for deleting from more than one table, which is supported by MySQL. Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688067/deleting-from-two-h2-tables-with-a-foreign-key) which shows how to do this with a subquery in `DELETE`. It should be something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM tableA 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM tableB 
    WHERE _iud = 'D'
)
```

Comment: Could you please tell if I have to match 2 columns of the tables  ( eg: id and name) then how should be the  query like - .. where id and name in ( select id, name)?

Comment: `id` is usually PK and it should be enough, are you sure that you need `name` as well?

Comment: yes, in my case id is not the PK. I think "where id and name in ( select id, name)" is working for me

Comment: Don't have H2 around to test this but maybe `... WHERE (id, name) IN (SELECT b.id, b.name FROM tableB AS b WHERE b._iud = 'D')`

Comment: I am trying to convert my update query - "UPDATE table1 AS mt, table2 AS et SET mt.country_name = et.country_name, mt.country_continent = et.country_continent WHERE mt.id = et.id" to h2  and I got stuck. I tried as UPDATE table1 AS mt , table2 as et SET (mt.country_name, mt.country_continent ) = ( SELECT et.country_name, et.country_continent   FROM table2 AS et WHERE mt.id = et.id  ) but the changed query fails in normal sql db. Could you please help me